# ¿Por qué AJAX (con Jquery) no me funciona en Localhost?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo pruebas con **ajax** de **jquery** y tengo el problema que a pesar de que mis sentencias son correctas me arroja error. Al inicio estaba haciéndolo sin servidor local (en file:///), hasta que en consola me arrojó el error siguiente:

> CORS request not HTTP.

Entonces recurrí a mi **localhost** y, aunque en **Google Chrome** ya no me arroja error, no puedo ver el contenido que quiero imprimir en pantalla, que es el contenido de un **objeto json**. Cuando uso **console.log()** me aparece **undefined**.

En **firefox** la consola me dice:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location:.../date.json
Line Number 1, Column 1:.
```

Dejaré mi código muy sencillo para que lo revisen por favor:

```
//[[HTML]]
<button>PUSH</button>
<div></div>
//[[HTML]]

//[[JAVA S]]
$( 'button' ).click( function () {
  $.get( "date.json", function(contenido) {
    console.log(contenido.nombre); //ESTO RETORNA UNDEFINED
    $( 'div' ).text( contenido.nombre ) //ESTO NO MUESTRA NADA
  } )
} )
//[[JAVA S]]

//JSON DOCUMENT LLAMADO date.json
{
"nombre" : "Ed"
}
```

Comment: Pon código completo por favor, el error puede estar entre esas lineas.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucioné, dejo la respuesta por si a otro se le presenta el mismo problema. Solo era cuestión de especificar el tipo de fichero que se quiere leer, en este caso JASON. Con ficheros que no sea json no es necesario especificar, porque aparentemente por defecto reconoce txt, html, php, etc (pero parece que json es un formato especial y se debe especificar):

```
$( 'button' ).click( function () {
  $.get( "date.json", function(contenido) {
    $( 'div' ).text( contenido.nombre ) //muestra Ed
  }, 'json' )
} )
```

Comment: márcala como aceptada, click en el check verde del costado :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('button').click( function () {
      $.get( "data.json", function(contenido) {
      console.log(contenido.nombre); //ESTO RETORNA UNDEFINED
      $('div').text( contenido.nombre ) //ESTO NO MUESTRA NADA
    })
})
});
```

//Prueba de esta forma

Comment: La consola arroja lo siguiente: ""GET http://localhost/php%20y%20sql/data.json 404 (Not Found)""

Comment: ah bueno, por error habias escrito "data.json" en lugar de "date.json"...ya lo corregi pero me sigue dando UNDEFINED en la consola, y en el cuerpo de la pagina no me muestra nada

Comment: el json está en la misma carpeta de donde tiene el php ? tu código está bien, la ruta de el json es posible que no este bien

Comment: Tengo instalado el XAMPP en la ubicacion OPT/LAMPP/HTDOCS...Pero, dado que ese lugar es poco accesible cree un acceso directo hacia Documentos/Web/Php y Sql/Practice/ Y aqui estan todos mis documentos php, incluido el AJAX.php con el que practico y el date.jason

Comment: que significa "value expected json(516)"?

Comment: "unexpected end of string" json(258)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).